# Hot reload doesn't work with Visual Studio 2022 + .NET 6 + ASP.NET Core 6 + Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hot-reload

I cannot use hot reload or any of the "edit and continue" features of Visual Studio 2022 when working with a .NET 6, ASP.NET Core 6 MVC site that I used "Visual Studio Container Tools" to add Docker support to the site. If I run the site under Kestrel or even IIS Express I can edit views or controller code and after saving my changes they are reflected immediately. When I switch to Docker (linux container) the only way to see my changes is to restart the application. I even tried creating a brand new MVC app using the built-in template and then just added docker support to see if it was my existing application causing the issue but it also doesn't work. I do not see anywhere in the documentation on Microsoft's site that says it should not work.